# getting error in using the newsapi php script

Tags: php, api, newsapi

```
$json = file_get_contents("https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=a1075eab1cfa4e129cb60c7dd8622322");
$news = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($news["articles"] as $i => $article) {
    echo '<h2>' . $article['title'] . '</h2>';
    echo '<img src="' . $article['urlToImage'] . '"/>';
    echo '<p>Published on ' . $article['publishedAt'] . '</p>';
    echo '<p>' . $article['description'] . '</p>';
    echo '<a href="' . $article['url'] . '">Read more</a>';
}
```

- i am using this code & it used to work till few days back.
  but now its returning error **PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/asdfgh/public_html/test.php on line 5**

Requesting to guide me to understand and resolve the error.

Comment: Code works for me as posted .. No errors / Warnings / Notices ..

Comment: You might exceeded your requests per month while never checking what's actually being decoded into `$news`